# How to show a hidden row when an icon is clicked?

Tags: jquery

I have a table where each row also has a hidden row that contains more data that can be revealed in an accordion when that particular row is clicked. I'm trying to figure out how to make the hidden row revealed only when the icon on each row is clicked rather than having the whole row 'active'. Thanks.

```
    <table class="table" width="100%;">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="accordion">
    <td><i class="icon-right-dir" id="arrow_2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion"></i></td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Data here</td>
    <td>Data here</td>
    <td>Data here</td>
    </tr>

         <tr class="hidden-row">
    <td colspan="12">

        <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">

        <h4>Data here</h4>

            </div>
            </div>

         </td>
    </tr>


....More rows here
</tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
                $(function() {
    var $table = $('.table');
    $table.find('.hidden-row').hide();

    $table.find('.accordion').click(function(){
      $table.find('.accordion').not(this).nextAll('.hidden-row:first').fadeOut(500);
      $(this).nextAll('.hidden-row:first').slideToggle("slow");
       $(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-right-dir icon-down-dir');
    });
});
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this handling all the presentation in CSS:

```js
$(function () {
  var $table = $("table");
  $table.find(".activator").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
table {width: 50%; margin: auto; border: 1px solid #ccf;}
.activator {cursor: pointer;}
.activator.open,
.activator:hover {background: #ccf;}
.activator.open .fa-plus,
.activator .fa-minus,
.activator + .hidden-row {display: none;}
.activator.open + .hidden-row {display: table-row;}
.activator.open .fa-minus {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 1's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 2's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 3's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 4's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 5's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 6's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 7's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 8's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 9's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 10's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you want it like an accordion behaviour, you can do:

```js
$(function () {
  var $table = $("table");
  $table.find(".activator").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("open"))
      $(this).removeClass("open");
    else {
      $(".open").removeClass("open");
      $(this).addClass("open");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {width: 50%; margin: auto; border: 1px solid #ccf;}
.activator {cursor: pointer;}
.activator.open,
.activator:hover {background: #ccf;}
.activator.open .fa-plus,
.activator .fa-minus,
.activator + .hidden-row {display: none;}
.activator.open + .hidden-row {display: table-row;}
.activator.open .fa-minus {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 1's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 2's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 3's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 4's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 5's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 6's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 7's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 8's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 9's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="activator">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Row 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden-row">
      <td>Row 10's Hidden</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I recently wrote [Evolution of Drop Down Menus and Exiting Them](https://blog.praveen.science/evolution-of-drop-down-menus-and-exiting-them/), where I have discussed some more interesting combinations.

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem is that as in my method each entire row is hidden row show. I don't want this, I only want the icon clickable and show the hidden row. The reason for this is that I have other buttons along the table row.

Comment: @JulianJ Just change the selector from `tr` to `tr .fa` dude... As simple as that.

Comment: Any chance of an example? I'm slightly confused. The selector it's currently to.table.activator.